# Pagination in backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pagination

I am working on backbone js using rest api with spring boot , in a jsp page to load more data or doing pagination whether i have to use backbone js or simple javascript . i got confused. Please give me suggestion for this confusion

Comment: This is too broad and it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please read the  FAQ on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 2):

Will make pagination like this 1… 3 4 5 6 7… 12.
For this we will need  PaginationView(backbone View) and pagination-view(template)

```
window.PaginationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#pagination-view").html()), // template
    link: "", // link
    page_count: null, // number of pages
    page_active: null, // active page
    page_show: 5, // pagination bar items number
    attributes: { // element attributes
        "class": "pagination"
    },
    initialize: function(params) { // constructor
       this.link = params.link;
       this.page_count = params.page_count;
       if (this.page_count <= this.page_show) {
           this.page_show = this.page_count;
       }
       this.page_active = params.page_active;
    },

    render: function(eventName) { // выдача
       ...
    }
```

});

Now consider the issue of logic. For the issuance of pagination, but rather block visible pages, we need to find the index of the beginning and end of these pages. We are looking for the number of elements to the active and after. That is, divide in half.

```
var range = Math.floor(this.page_show / 2);
var nav_begin = this.page_active - range;
if (this.page_show % 2 == 0) { //If an even number
    nav_begin++;
}
var nav_end = this.page_active + range;
```

Next, we need to know, or we have to give out "..." on each side. We set up two variables, which will show whether it is necessary:

```
var left_dots = true;
var right_dots = true;
```

So, when we need "..." when it began more than 2 (left) and when less than the end - 1 (right). To do this, write two checks, which analyze one particular case. It consists in the fact that if we have two active, the dispensing unit has one more element.

1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 12

And just at the end.

1 ... 7 8 9 10 11 12

```
if (nav_begin <= 2) {
    nav_end = this.page_show;
    if (nav_begin == 2) {
         nav_end++;
    } 
    nav_begin = 1;
    left_dots = false;
}

if (nav_end >= this.page_count - 1 ) {
    nav_begin = this.page_count - this.page_show + 1;
    if (nav_end == this.page_count - 1) {
           nav_begin--;
    }
    nav_end = this.page_count;
    right_dots = false;
}
```

After this need to send to template

```
$(this.el).html( this.template({
    link: this.link,
    page_count: this.page_count,
    page_active: this.page_active,
    nav_begin: nav_begin,
    nav_end: nav_end,
    left_dots: left_dots,
    right_dots: right_dots
}) );
```

Template pagination-view(I used twitter bootstrap)

```
<ul>

  <% if (page_active > 1) { %>
     <li><a href="<%= link %><%= page_active-1 %>">«</a></li>
  <% } %>
  <% if (left_dots) {%>
     <li><a href="<%= link %>1">1</a></li>
     <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
  <% } %>

  <% for (var i = nav_begin; i <= nav_end; i++) { %> 
      <li <% if (page_active == i) print('class="active"') %> ><a href="<%=    link %><%= i %>"><%= i %></a></li> 
 <% } %>

 <% if (right_dots) {%>
     <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
     <li><a href="<%= link %><%= page_count %>"><%= page_count %></a></li>
 <% } %>

 <% if (page_active < page_count) { %>
    <li><a  href="<%= link %><%= page_active+1 %>">»</a></li>
 <% } %>
</ul>
```

P.S. Quite simply, take and use :).

P.S here is working git for situations like this https://gist.github.com/io41/838460 (not my)